# Update a value in sql on Insert by using a Rule; Having problems with OLD

Tags: sql, psql, rule

When I have a table that's like

```
AccNum     Location
76         North
87         West
92         South
```

And say I want to insert 76 again but I can only have it in there once so that on an insert for (76,East) I want my table to look like

```
AccNum    Location
76        East
87        West
92        South
```

This is my code

```
CREATE RULE ChangeValue AS ON INSERT TO ItemLocations
     WHERE OLD.AccNum = NEW.AccNum
        DO INSTEAD
                UPDATE ItemLocations
                SET
                        Loc = NEW.Loc
                WHERE
                        AccNum = NEW.AccNum
;
```

But I am currently getting

```
There is an entry for table "old", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 95.+, you can use `on conflict`:

```
insert into t(AccNum, Location)
    select 76, 'East'
    on conflict do update set Location = 'East';
```

Or:

```
insert into t(AccNum, Location)
    select 76, 'East'
    on conflict do update set Location = EXCLUDED.Location;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm actually trying to figure out what's wrong with my rules in general with this question, I can't seem to get my rules right